# In a cournot's duopoly with firms 'A' and 'B' given the following conditions what are the strategies(output) that 'A' never chooses.

Tags: game-theory

The total output is given by
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{N+1} \right)\frac{a-c}{b}$$ with $N=2$.
The inverse demand function is $P=a-bx$ with $a=5, b=1, c=2$, where $x$ is the total output and $c$ is the cost which is a constant.

Firms 'A' and 'B' are both rational and
Firm 'A' knows that firm 'B' is rational

The possible strategies(output) for 'A' are
$Q_a=\{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2\}$. Which of these is never chosen by 'A'?
[what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82qwb.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your attempt, so we know where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: Hey @Maadhav i have added a pic of what I have done.I am confused how to proceed further or whether this is even the right approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your attempt. I have added my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

$$Q^*_A = \frac{5-Q_B}{2}$$

$$Q^*_B = \frac{5-Q_A}{2}$$

Using IEDS (iterative elimination of dominant strategy) method,

$\text{Step 1}$

Note that $Q^*_A \le \frac52$ since $Q_B \ge 0$

Similarly, $Q^*_B \le \frac52$ since $Q_A \ge 0$

$\text{Step 2}$

Since, $Q^*_B \le \frac52$, and Firm $A$ knows that Firm $B$ is rational,

$\implies\frac{5-Q_B}2 \ge \frac{5-\frac52}2$

$\implies Q^*_A \ge \frac54$

Since, Firm $B$ is not aware of $A$ being rational, this is where the iterative elimination ends.

$1.25 \le Q_A \le 2.5$

In case, it is not the total cost but the marginal cost that is constant (in which case, the reaction curves will change), we get

$0.9375 \le Q_A \le 1.25$

Answer (score 0):

Although, the equilibrium quantity for both the firms comes out to be $Q_A^*=Q_B^*=\frac53$ as in your attempt, this does not agree with the bound that is imposed on the total quantity.

$Q_T = Q_A + Q_B= 2$

Neither firm $A$ nor firm $B$ would choose on an output greater than half of the total quantity. So that, $Q_A \le 1$ and $Q_B \le 1$.

The profit equation for firm $A$ is:

$\pi = (5-(Q_A+Q_B))Q_A - 2 = (5-2) Q_A -2 = 3Q_A -2$

The profit cannot be less than zero, so we get a lower bound:

$\pi \ge 0 \implies Q_A \ge \frac23$

Since, $\frac23 \le Q_A \le 1$

$Q_A \in \{0.75,1\}$

Comment: Hey @Maadhav I think there's something wrong as this was not accepted as the correct answer. I think its because you have not considered the fact that 'B' does not know that 'A' is rational. Will it change the answer in any way?

Comment: @ashwinmanoj We are given that they are both rational and 'A' knows that 'B' is rational. And, we are left to decide what outputs 'A' will not choose from given the knowledge possessed by 'A'. 'B' being rational will similarly not choose an output that leads to a loss or an excess output that might lead to overstock that doesn't get sold.

Comment: @ashwinmanoj One thing that might be wrong is the cost being constant, might imply that marginal cost is constant rather than total cost. It would lead to nash equilibria of quantities 1 for both 'A' and 'B'. This checks out by the total quantity formula. Do you happen to know the solution of the problem?

Comment: I do not know the answer to the question, but one hint I got was that we have to solve this question using IEDS(iterative elimination of dominant strategy) method

Comment: @ashwinmanoj Hey, I've added another answer as per your hint. I really hope that works. Please let know what the answer is when you discover it, I am more than interested at this point, haha.

Comment: I have tried the the solutions you gave me and worked up the problem to get same results. However its still coming up as incorrect. I think we've been missing something very trivial. Anyway I'll let you know when i find the solution.